# Swift why unwrapping optional by guarding against NIL is not working

Tags: swift, option-type

I am new to Swift, but am curious about the behaviour of optional unwrapping.

Is there any explanation why guarding against `!= nil` is not unwrapping the optional?

As a simple example:

```swift
func hasC(_ s: String?) -> Bool {
  guard s != nil else {
    return false
  }

  return s!.contains("c")
}
```

I need to put the exclamation sign and explicitly unwrap the value, even though it seems to be clear that at the last line `s` is not an optional string anymore.

I would love to hear the reasoning behind such a behaviour and how to unwrap the value properly in such a case?

creating extra variable seems ugly:

```swift
guard let s = s else { ... }
```

and guarding against not boolean condition is not working:

```swift
guard s else { ... }
```

Repl: https://repl.it/@valerii/optional-unwrap

Comment: `creating extra variable seems ugly:` whether you find it ugly or not, optional binding is the way to go. If you do a `nil` check and then force unwrap, that can still cause crashes in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: code must be stable, not beauty. I edit my answer. 3th code is better for your taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `s` is still `Optional`, so whether you did a `nil` check or not is irrelevant. The `nil` check is done in runtime, while the type system is doing a compile-time check. The only way to ensure `s` can never be `nil` is via optional binding `if let` or `guard let`.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that an equating operator, e.g. `==`, `!=` or any comparing operators have nothing to do with unwrapping an optional value from the point of view of the compiler.
A `guard` statement has 2 general use cases. One is to guard against a `boolean` value, which is produced by an equating or comparing operator, like in the following example:

```
guard ["foo", "bar"].contains("foo") == true else { return }
guard 10 > 5 else { return }
```

While another role of the `guard` statement is to unwrap optionals, which is written in a `guard let` or `guard var` syntax. For example:

```
guard let unwrappedValue = anOptionalValue else { return }
```

That specific syntax, lets the compiler know that you're trying to unwrap the value, and you get an unwrapped value as a result if the unwrapping is successful.

Sure, while creating another variable/constant may seem "ugly", that is the way to go in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring a new variable using guard,  function parameter is optional so thats why its allowing you to unwrap even after guard statement

```
func hasC(_ s: String?) -> Bool {
    if let containsValueInString  = s ,   containsValueInString.contains("c"){
         return true
    }
    return false

}
```

or Simpler you can use Optional chaining with nil coalescing operator

```
func hasC(_ s: String?) -> Bool {
  return  s?.contains("c") ?? false

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `you are not unwrapping with the guard`? that is what i am doing. The thing i would like to have - unwrapped `s` after the `!= nil` check.

Comment: orignal guard statment is `guard let getString = s else {return} `

Comment: getString is now unwraped

Answer (score 0):

`guard` doesn't unwrap anything just by itself. It's like a special kind of `if`. `guard let` unwraps, but it's just a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong format

```
func hasC(_ s: String?) -> Bool {
  guard let input = s else {return false}

  return input.contains("c")
}
```

and you can do like that:

```
func hasC(_ s: String?) -> Bool {
  if let input = s {
  return input.contains("c")
  }
  return false
}
```

or you can make your output nullable like this:

```
func hasC(_ s: String?) -> Bool? {
      return s?.contains("c")
}
```

or

```
func hasC(_ s: String?) -> Bool {
        return s?.contains("c") ?? false
}
```

it is not ugly anymore. with lower lines.
best regards

Comment: this is still **creation of a new variable** :) The only way to unwrap the value in swift is to create another var?

Comment: @ValeriiVasin it is swift nullability standard. your new variable will kill at the end of the function. don't worry about it. I will edit my answer for 2 options for this problem. second is with if statement